# Reference for upper and lower bounds on $e^x$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm looking for a reference for deriving the following commonly used upper and lower bounds for $e^x$:

$$1 - x \le e^{-x}$$
and, assuming $x \le 1/2$,

$$1 - x \ge e^{-2x}.
$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First Inequality:** Let $f(x)=e^{-x}-(1-x)$. Then $f'(x)=-e^{-x}+1$.  This is $0$ at $x=0$, negative if $x \lt 0$, and positive for $x \gt 0$. So $f(x)$ reaches an absolute  minimum at $x=0$. The minimum value is $0$, so $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$.

**Second Inequality:** Let $g(x)=(1-x)-e^{-2x}$. Then $g'(x)=-1+2e^{-2x}$. This is $0$ for $x=(\ln 2)/2$.
We find that $g'(x)$ is positive for $x\lt (\ln 2)/2$, and negative for $x \gt (\ln 2)/2$. The function $g(x)$ is increasing up to $x=(\ln 2)/2$, then decreasing.

We have $g(0)=0$.  Since $g(x)$ is increasing until $(\ln 2)/2$, it follows that $g(x)$ is *negative* when $x$ is negative, so our inequality fails if $x \lt 0$.

For positive $x$, $g(x)$ increases up to $x=(\ln 2)/2$, and then decreases. After a while it will become negative. Let us check whether $g(x)$ is still positive at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Calculate. We get $g(1/2)\approx 0.132$. So $g(x) \ge 0$ at least in the interval $[0,1/2]$. In fact $g(x) \ge 0$ from $0$ to a bit beyond $0.79$.

**Remark:** There will be few standard North American calculus books that don't do the first inequality. Usually it is done in the equivalent version $1+x \le e^x$. It is an early application of the connection between increasing functions and positive derivatives. The inequality (among many others) is mentioned [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Related_inequalities)

The second inequality uses the same method, but the details involve more work.